# How to get all roles and associated permissions to them

Tags: eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to get all the roles whether they were assigned some permissions or not, if were assigned permissions then want to show them in front of each role using eloquent.

The Query I am trying

```
    $roles = role::select('roles.*','role_permissions.permission_id')
    ->leftjoin('role_permissions', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_permissions.role_id')
    ->get();
```

Problem with this query is that, it repeats the role if multiple permissions were assigned to role.
for example:

[image: It is showing result in this order]

It is showing result in this order (*this is just for quick understanding*).
How can I have result this way `['role_id' => 1, 'permission_id' => [1,2] ]` with eloquent. 
 **Role model**

```
public function permissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\permission::class, 'role_permissions');
}
```

**Permission model**

```
public function roles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Role::class, 'role_permissions');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection methods:

```
Role::with('role_permissions')->all()->map(function(Role $role){
  return $role->permission_ids = $role->permissions->pluck('id');
})
```

Or you can use custom getter in Role model:

```
public function getPermissionIdsAttribute()
{
  return $this->permissions->pluck('id');
}
$role->permission_ids;
```